# VS Code ESLint Checking for quick fixes... not working

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

I'm not sure if it was a recent update, but for some reason I'm not getting the quick fixes for ESLint any longer. It will say "Checking for quick fixes...", but I will not display any. In the ESLint server I can see the fix available, but the command is missing in VS Code.

[image: Checking for quick fixes...]

```
[Trace - 5:30:49 PM] Received response 'textDocument/codeAction - (13)' in 0ms.
Result: [
    {
        "title": "Disable no-unused-vars for this line",
        "command": {
            "title": "Disable no-unused-vars for this line",
            "command": "eslint.applyDisableLine",
            "arguments": [
                {
                    "uri": "file:///d%3A/Development/sfdx/insider/force-app/main/default/lwc/apexImperativeMethod/apexImperativeMethod.js",
                    "version": 14,
                    "ruleId": "no-unused-vars"
                }
            ]
        },
        "kind": "quickfix"
    },
    {
        "title": "Disable no-unused-vars for the entire file",
        "command": {
            "title": "Disable no-unused-vars for the entire file",
            "command": "eslint.applyDisableFile",
            "arguments": [
                {
                    "uri": "file:///",
                    "version": 14,
                    "ruleId": "no-unused-vars"
                }
            ]
        },
        "kind": "quickfix"
    },
    {
        "title": "Show documentation for no-unused-vars",
        "command": {
            "title": "Show documentation for no-unused-vars",
            "command": "eslint.openRuleDoc",
            "arguments": [
                {
                    "uri": "file:///",
                    "version": 14,
                    "ruleId": "no-unused-vars"
                }
            ]
        },
        "kind": "quickfix"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Same was happening to me as well and after trying multiple things what worked for me was a clean reinstall of Code which meant uninstalling Code, deleting the extension folder and and installing the code followed by extensions. And quick fix is back.

Comment: Thanks. I will give that a go as well.